# Wrong difference returned between two pixelaccess objects

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I have a function which takes as parameters two [PixelAccess](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/PixelAccess.html) objects which essentially are two images which are converted to a multi-dimensional array of pixels of the type (image1pixels[x,y]) , then it subtracts each tuple of pixels on the width and height of both the images and then appends the subtractions of pixels inside an array named `c` ; The function then returns the sum of all the tuples in the array.

Here is the function:

```py
def difference(pix1, pix2):
    size = width, height = img.size;
    result = 0;
    array = [];

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            c = tuple(map(sub, pix2[x, y], pix1[x, y]));
            array.append(c);
            result = abs(add(map(sum, array)));
    return result;
```

Here to have an idea, when I print `c`, this is what is printed:

```sh
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(-253, -253, -253)
(-210, -210, -210)
(-168, -168, -168)
(-147, -147, -147)
(-48, -48, -48)
(-13, -13, -13)
(-29, -29, -29)
(-48, -48, -48)
(-48, -48, -48)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
```

I have to compare two images using this function, the expected difference should be `17988` but my function returns `9174`.

I just want to know if my logic is wrong or if I'm coding the wrong way here knowing python is not my primary everyday language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd love to know who keeps telling folk to use the`PixelAccess` method, or any `for` loops with Python image processing - it is very **sub-optimal**. Even the official documentation says to avoid it! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html

Comment: I don't know, my teacher wrote this, she's not really good at programming...